# Access to externally mounted folder on Linux

Tags: linux, centos, centos6

I'm trying to free access to a specific user to a folder mounted on `/mnt/blockstorage`.

```
ls /mnt/blockstorage/

drwxr-xr-x 3 joe joe joe 4096 Jun 17 14:23 joe
```

I created a link to the user to access the shared folder.

```
ls /Home/joe/

lrwxrwxrwx 1 joe joe 23 Jun 17 18:08 joeFolder -> /mnt/blockstorage/joe/
```

Does not work.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Hi.. Can you explain that clearly? Are you able to create link in /Home/joe/? or are you not able to write into the folder using that link?

Comment: I create a link to the folder, but the user does not have permission to access and write.

Comment: Error - open for read: no such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Folder `/mnt/blockstorage/` permissions should be changed so that the user `joe` could read or write data into that folder. Unfortunately It is not possible to change permissions of files or folders in `/mnt` directory.
But you can create a `/etc/fstab` file entry so that the user `joe` can R/W to the folder `/mnt/blockstorage`. Please refer following link for more information.
http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1513822.html